# create macro for message according to time

Tags: c, macros, printf

I'm trying to create a macro for my program in C to use in a *printf*

```
#define TIME(t) \
    (t->tm_hour >= 6 && t->tm_hour < 12) ? "Good morning":"" && \
    (t->tm_hour >= 12 && t->tm_hour < 18) ? "Good afternoon":"" && \
    (t->tm_hour >= 18 && t->tm_hour < 23) ? "Good night":""
```

the *printf* function is the same as below

```
printf("%s\n", TIME(t));
```

in compilation is returning me alert C4474

```
C4474: too many arguments passed for format string
```

Does anyone know why the error?

Comment: What do you expect this `? : && ? : ...` syntax to do?

Comment: You've got a problem that you're never going to see "Good night"; there are very few numbers that are simultaneously 18 or bigger and also less than zero.  You probably want `… >= 18 || … < 6`.  You also need to fix the `? : && ? :` notation pointed out.  The RHS of the `&&` is not going to be evaluated.  It's also good practice to wrap parentheses around a macro expression, and the parameters (so use `(t)->tm_hour` in the macro expansion).

Comment: Good idea to out a `()` around the whole macro.

Comment: @jhonathan Leffler My error when writing in the forum. the correct is `< 23`

Comment: I have to ask why you want to do this as a macro? I could get having the hours as defines so you can configure for different regions, but trying to do the whole thing as a macro?

Comment: I like to write expressions that check for `x` being within a range as: `low_limit <= x && x <= upper_limit` because that clearly echos the mathematical notation that you'd use (`low_limit <= x <= upper_limit`).  I'm a little surprised I don't see this suggested in coding guidelines very often.

Comment: Currently it only shows Good morning even though it is night time. Why do you think it's bad to use macro?

Comment: @Carol `Why do you think it's bad to use macro?` could fill a book. Here are some of the highlights: **a)** As a macro all that code gets copied everytime you use it. As a function it exists once and is called from multiple places. **b)** As you can see by asking the question, it is more complex. An if-else-else in a function and you'd be off writing the next piece of code instead of posting here. **c)** Macros can make code harder to read and debug. Your name for example is bad - should be `GREETING_STR_FROM_TIME` or similar.

Comment: Note that you'd have a more flexible macro if, instead of passing a `struct tm *` to it, you called it with `t->tm_hour` (just the hour).  It would also be more succinct.  It seems odd that between 23:00 of one day and 06:00 of the next, there is no greeting for the user.  However, that's more a UX issue than the base coding issue which has been resolved adequately by the accepted answer.

Comment: Perfect example of where you should use a function, not a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the else-conditions cascade:

```
#define TIME(t) \
   (((t)->tm_hour >=  6 && (t)->tm_hour < 12) ? "Good morning" : \
    ((t)->tm_hour >= 12 && (t)->tm_hour < 18) ? "Good afternoon" : \
    ((t)->tm_hour >= 18 && (t)->tm_hour < 23) ? "Good night" : "")
```